# How to I do an array with a JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, joptionpane

The question asks "The number of fuel tanks can only be (2,4,8,10, 15,20)" this is aNbrTanks in the code below. I been trying to use an array to have these inputs. But then I get the error of Object cant be converted to int or int[] to int. I need to ask for input by JOptionPane and then ask again if it doesn't meet the standards.

```
package project2;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class VehicleApp {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
     //name
        String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your first name");
        while(firstName.equals("")){
           firstName =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid first name");
        }
        String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your last name");
        
        while(lastName.equals("")){
            lastName =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid first name");
        }
        String aName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        
        //phone
        String aphone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your number");
        while(aphone.length()!=10){
            aphone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid phone number");
        }
        String aPhone = ("" + aphone).replaceAll("(...)(...)(....)", "$1-$2-$3");
        //vechicle number
        int aNbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Vehicles"));
        while(aNbrVehicles < 1  || aNbrVehicles > 10 ){
            aNbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("valid number of Vehicles"));
        }
        
        //fuel tank
        int aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Tanks"));     
       
     
            
        VehicleFactory JarApp = new VehicleFactory(aName, aPhone, aNbrVehicles, aNbrTanks);
       
        JarApp.calcManufacturingCost();
        JarApp.calcFuelTankCost();
        JarApp.calcSubtotal();
        JarApp.calcTax();
        JarApp.calcTotal();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, JarApp.getSummary());

}
    }
```

I just need ideas or help figuring out how to get an array or a statement that be used as int aNbrTanks like the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

You could request values in a loop, as you suggest anyway.
My example shows the loop you can use. There are more efficient ways to test for the allowed values.

```
int aNbrTanks = 0;
while (true) {
   try {
       aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Tanks"));the number of Vehicles"));
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       e.printStackTrace(e);
   }

   if (aNbrTanks==2) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Coming back to your title question, you can use JOptionPane with an Object[], not int[]. It will then convert your list of choices into a JComboBox. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] choices = new Object[]{2,3,5,8};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(choices));
    
    Object choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of Tanks", "Tanks", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, choices, 2);
    
    System.out.println(choice);
}
```